# Splitting same frame material into multiple slide in beamer

Tags: beamer

I have a single slide with the following two reference lines in beamer.

```
\begin{frame}{Test}
The first line
\vskip{3cm}
The second line
\end{frame}
```

I want to split this two lines into two successive slide. One try is

```
\begin{frame}{Test}
The first line
\vskip{3cm}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Test}
The first line
\vskip{3cm}
The second line
\end{frame}
```

But here the problem is in the first slide  `The First line` positions in the center and in the second slide, it shifts to the top, which does not look good for successive slideshow. Can I do something so that when changing from first slide to the second slide does not change the position of the first line?

Comment: Please don't post just code fragments. Always make a small, but compilable test file.

Answer (score 0):

One way for solving your problem is to use `\uncover` instruction:

**Edit:**   considered is OP comment below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\uncover<1->{The first line}  % observe added -

\vskip3cm
\uncover<2>{The second line}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what you looking for?

Comment: Sorry, in the second slide, both the first and the second line will be printed

Comment: @TanmoyPati,that is not evident from your question ... but this not hard to achieve. :-). See edited answer.

Comment: perfect. Thanks

Comment: @TanmoyPati In addition to saying thanks, please consider accepting and upvoting an answer which solved your problem.